# Python getting Data from Coinmarketcap Website API

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I would like to only get the "price_usd" value of e.g. Bitcoin from https://coinmarketcap.com/api/
I've tried this code below, but I can't figure out how to only get this one value.. I am using Python 3.5.3. I'd be glad for every help!

```
import json 
import requests 

r = requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/')
for coin in r.json():
    print(coin)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
import json 
import requests 

r = requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/')
for coin in r.json():
    print(coin["price_usd"])
```

You can also use the `get` method to lookup values from a dictionary. It allows you to provide a default value if the key is missing:

```
for coin in r.json():
    print(coin.get("price_usd", "U$S Price not provided"))
```